# PostgreSql Cross tab

Tags: json, postgresql

I am new to PostgreSQL and also facing new challenge. Here I have table like this

For eg:

| name | age | x |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Vijay | 22 | [addr,1,"xxxxxxxxxx"] |
| Vijay | 22 | [addr,2, "yyyyyyyyy"] |

script is

```
SELECT name, age , x.* 
FROM zzzzzz, jsonb_array_elements(address::jsonb) AS x
```

but i want to show the result like this

| name | age | addr 1 | addr 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Vijay | 22 | xxxxxxxxxx | yyyyyyyyy |

Answer (score 0):

This is a really bad database design, but anyways.

You can do a self join on the name, and filter the two tables based on the occurance of `addr,1` or `addr,2`  in the JSONB column.

```
select t1.name, t1.age, 
       t1.x ->> 2 as addr1, 
       t2.x ->> 2 as addr2 
from the_table t1
  join the_table t2 on t1.name = t2.name 
where t1.x @> '["addr",1]'
  and t2.x @> '["addr",2]'
```

This query makes the following two assumptions (stemming from the sample data)

1. The actual address is always the third element in the array
2. There are no other numbers in the array, 
   e.g. if you have `["addr", 2, "xxxxxxxxxx", 1]` then the above would fail. It that might happen, but you are sure that the `addr` keyword is **always** the first element and the second element always indicates whether it's the first or second address:

```
where t1.x ->> 0 = 'addr' and t1.x ->> 1 = '1'
  and t2.x ->> 0 = 'addr' and t2.x ->> 1 = '2'
```